# jquery start and stop timer

Tags: jquery, timer, intervals

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').keyup(function(e){
       if(e.keyCode == 32){

        if(foo == 1)
        {
            clearInterval(myinterval);
            foo = 0;
        } else {

        $('#h2').text('STOPPA MED SPACE!');
        var start       = new Date;
        var foo;
        var myinterval  = setInterval(function() {$('.Timer').text((new Date - start) / 1000); }, 10);

        foo = 1;

        }

       }
    });
});
</script>
```

Above is my jQuery code. When I press the space button on my keyboard I start a timer which count up. How can I stop this timer if I press space again? I can always add a var foo = 0; which tells if the interval is ongoing or not. But how can I stop this interval?

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
var yourInterval = setInterval(function() {....},10);

clearInterval(yourInterval);
```

See the docs for [`setInterval()`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) and [`clearInterval()`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval).

Comment: Ok, I've done some changes. But I still can't get it to pause when I press space. See my edit.

Comment: This will need a lot of modification to run with milliseconds?